# Initialize java byte array: possible loss of precision

Tags: java, byte

I am initializing a `byte[]` in **Java**, using *hexadecimal* or *binary* notation.

It seems that auto-casting to byte is not done when the value *approaches* the capacity of a byte.

Solution is explicit cast to `byte`.

```java
$ javac bitsandbytes/ByteBufferTest.java 
bitsandbytes/ByteBufferTest.java:9: error: possible loss of precision
    static byte[] byteArray = { 0xFF, (byte) 0xCC, 0xCC, 0b1000_0000, 0x2F, 0x01 };
                                ^
  required: byte
  found:    int
bitsandbytes/ByteBufferTest.java:9: error: possible loss of precision
    static byte[] byteArray = { 0xFF, (byte) 0xCC, 0xCC, 0b1000_0000, 0x2F, 0x01 };
                                                   ^
  required: byte
  found:    int
bitsandbytes/ByteBufferTest.java:9: error: possible loss of precision
    static byte[] byteArray = { 0xFF, (byte) 0xCC, 0xCC, 0b1000_0000, 0x2F, 0x01 };
                                                         ^
  required: byte
  found:    int
3 errors
```

[image]

Comment: What do you by mean _approaches_? Do you mean _exceeds_?

Comment: Forgot `byte` is signed in Java, forget this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems that auto-casting to byte is not done when the value approaches the capacity of a byte.

No, it happens when the value is out of range. A `byte` in Java is in the range [-128, 127]. So `0xcc` is out of range, for example... although this has nothing to do with which base you express the literal in.

If you have:

```
byte[] x = { 127 };
System.out.println(x[0]);
```

that will print 127, because it's in the range of `byte`. If you have:

```
byte[] x = { (byte) 128 };
System.out.println(x[0]);
```

... that will print -128. That would be very unexpected if you didn't have an explicit cast.

Admittedly an error message about "precision" is odd - and not what I receive. I see this:

> error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte

It *is* a lossy conversion, so that's fine. I wouldn't talk about that being a *precision* issue though, which is what I'd expect for a conversion of (say) `double` to `float`.

In terms of the JLS, the relevant section is [5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2), which applies to each VariableInitializer in the ArrayInitializer.

This is the important part (emphasis mine):

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, *and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable*.

The examples you've given aren't representable in the `byte` type, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks @Jon. I am however puzzled why hex or binary notation is interpreted like this for `byte` types while I can perfectly define an `int` as `0xFFFF_FFFF` without complaints from the compiler.

Comment: @Campa: It's a bit odd, yes. The JLS explicitly says that it's a bug for an `int` literal not to fit into 32 bits. I think the difference is that this *is* an integer literal - whereas there's no such thing as a "byte literal". There's just an implicit conversion from an integer literal to a byte. What you may find really surprising is that `byte x = 0xff;` is not valid, but `byte x = 0xffff_ffff;` *is* valid...